# Issues attempting to display data from JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery

### Premise:

I'm playing around with javascript and have been trying to display a populated JSON file with an array of people on the browser. I've managed to display it through ajax, but now I'm trying to perform the same task with jQuery.

### Problem:

The problem is that it keeps saying *`customerdata[i]`* is `undefined` and can't seem to figure out why.

```js
$(function() {
  console.log('Ready');

  let tbody = $("#customertable tbody");

  var customerdata = [];

  $.getJSON("MOCK_DATA.json", function(data) {
    customerdata.push(data);
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    //Cell for name
    let nameTD = $('<td>').text(customerdata[i].first_name + ", " + customerdata[i].last_name);

    //Cell for birthdate
    let mDate = moment(customerdata[i].birthdate);
    let formattedmDate = mDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    let birthdateTD = $('<td>').text(formattedmDate);

    //Cell for Address 
    let addressTD = $('<td>').html("City: " + customerdata[i].city + '<br>' + "Email: " + customerdata[i].email + '<br>' + '<a href=' + customerdata[i].website + '>Website</a>');

    //Cell for Credits
    let creditTD = $('<td>').text(customerdata[i].credits);


    let row = $('<tr>').append(nameTD).append(birthdateTD).append(addressTD).append(creditTD);

    tbody.append(row);
  }
})
```

### SAMPLE CONTENT OF ***`MOCK_DATA.json`***

```
[
  {"id":1,"first_name":"Tracey","last_name":"Jansson","email":"tjansson0@discuz.net","gender":"Female","ip_address":"167.88.183.95","birthdate":"1999-08-25T17:24:23Z","website":"http://hello.com","city":"Medellín","credits":7471},
  {"id":2,"first_name":"Elsa","last_name":"Tubbs","email":"etubbs1@uol.com.br","gender":"Female","ip_address":"61.26.221.132","birthdate":"1999-06-28T17:22:47Z","website":"http://hi.com","city":"At Taḩālif","credits":6514}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you're pushing an array into an array, meaning you're a level deeper than you want to be when iterating over the data.

Secondly, `$.getJSON` is an asynchronous task. It's not complete, meaning `customerdata` isn't populated by the time your jQuery is trying to append the data.

You should wait for `getJSON` to resolve before you append, by chaining a `then` to your AJAX call.

```
$.getJSON("MOCK_DATA.json")
    .then(function(customerdata){



        for(var i = 0; i < 200; i++){
           //Cell for name
           let nameTD = $('<td>').text(customerdata[i].first_name + ", " + customerdata[i].last_name);

            //Cell for birthdate
           let mDate = moment(customerdata[i].birthdate);
           let formattedmDate = mDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'); 
           let birthdateTD = $('<td>').text(formattedmDate);

           //Cell for Address 
           let addressTD = $('<td>').html("City: " + 
           customerdata[i].city + '<br>' + "Email: " + 
           customerdata[i].email + '<br>' + '<a 
           href='+customerdata[i].website+'>Website</a>');

           //Cell for Credits
           let creditTD = $('<td>').text(customerdata[i].credits);


           let row = $('<tr>').append(nameTD).append(birthdateTD).append(addressTD).append(creditTD);

         tbody.append(row);
      }

})
```

You also won't need to define customerdata as an empty array at all with this approach.

Comment: Thank you so much! I tested it out and it worked! I'm still learning more about jQuery and your second point was extremely helpful, I appreciated that you pointed it out.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that data is already an array.

so you should use:

```
customerdata = data;
```

otherwhise you are creating an array in the pos 0 with all the data

Comment: I attempted to do that and tried to console.log(customerdata) and it's showing that customerdata is empty